# How did I output indices of the two numbers in leetcode?

Tags: arrays, c

Question: Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target. You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice. You can return the answer in any order.

```
  /**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int i;
    int j;
    returnSize = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
     for (i = 0; i < numsSize - 1; ++i) {
         for (j = i + 1; j < numsSize; ++j) {
             if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                 returnSize[0] = i;
                 returnSize[1] = j;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
             break;
         }
     }
    return returnSize;
}
```

Comment: Also if `nums` is youre "returned array" and you're returning `returnSize` then `nums` should be a double pointer and you would call malloc on the dereferenced pointer so that the caller has access to `nums`. In your current code, when the function terminates, the pointer allocated to `nums` is lost.

Comment: The function return value should be the array not the size.

Comment: `nums = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numsSize + 10 * sizeof(int));` That's wrong. It throws away the input array which makes it impossible to compare with the original input numbers.

Comment: If I do not write like this nums = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numsSize + 10 * sizeof(int)); It happened runtime error, that is the space is not enough. What should I do?

Comment: You are not supposed to change `nums` in any way. It is **input**. You are supposed to just read the numbers that are already stored in that array.

Comment: The only problem now is that my program output only outputs ], What caused this situation？

Comment: What do you mean by "now"? What have you changed? What do you mean "outputs only ]"? Your function outputs two integers seperated by a comma. So how could it possibly be outputting `]`. Unless it is code we can't see. You need to explain things much more clearly.

Comment: Think about the caller of this function ... what happens there? `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; int *x = twoSum(arr, 10, 19, NULL); /*...*/ free(x);` ???

Comment: But I can’t see the caller of this function, what should I do?

Comment: You do what everyone else does when they need to test the code. Write your own test code that calls this function. Write lots of test cases with different input. Verify that each test case returns the right result. It's just basic software development and testing.